# How to check if an user attribute is a certain value for different route groups in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, security, symfony-3.4

The system:

A user is tied to a company. A company has a License. A license has 2 expiration dates. expirationBasic and expirationExtended.

What I want:
For 50 routes I want to check if the license of the company of the logged in user has an expirationExtended > now.

For 50 routes I want to check if the license of the company of the logged in user has an expirationBasic > now.

I am using symfony 3.4

Answer (score 0):

This question is lacking details, like what you'd like the system to do when the check fails.  There are at least two common ways to handle this.

The "Symfonic" way would be to add an [event filter](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html).  Create a new class that extends `EventSubscriberInterface` and drop it in your `EventSubscriber` directory / namespace.  When the appropriate event is triggered your method can perform the checks and throw and `AccessDeniedHttpException`.

Assuming your 50 routes go to multiple controllers, another solution is to write an abstract controller class which is set as the parent of your final controllers.  This base class can then perform the check against the logged in user.